# Why am I not getting an exact time when adding days to a time?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, datetime, .net-6.0, date-manipulation

In .NET Core 6 I am getting a funny result when adding days, and it only happens in one project but not in another.

```
var time = 3.2986111640930176;
var firstDate = new DateTime(2023, 7, 1);
var newDate = firstDate.AddDays(time);
var ticks = newDate.Ticks;
```

I expect the newDate to be 4 July 2023 07:10 which it is. But when looking at the ticks I get this: 6382405140000**5**0000 when I was expecting 638240514000000000 (which it is in another project).

I use the following code to round the result which is how I found the diff:

```
public static DateTime RoundUp(this DateTime dt, TimeSpan d)
{            
        return new DateTime(((dt.Ticks + d.Ticks / 2) / d.Ticks) * d.Ticks);
}
```

In my other project because I get 638240514000000000 so it rounds fine to 07:10 but the wrong results gives me 07:11.

I also spun up a new console app and tried the above code and also got the wrong result (6382405140000**5**0000).

I am totally confused whats causing it and why is it different in other project.

Comment: I just wouldn't use a `double` value like this if I wanted precision.

Comment: If you're going to add an arbitrary value, use TimeSpan https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timespan

Comment: If you introduce floating point values, expect floating point arithmetic to happen. And this is what you'll have to deal with. Is there a specific reason for using a `double`?

Comment: I do not really understand why there is an issue with the double. Could someone please show me how you would do it to make it same? TIA

Comment: Hi, based on your scenario and description, did you tried to parse the value using floting or decimal type? Or based on suggeted comments did you able to resolve that?

Answer (score 0):

The issue you are encountering is due to the fact that the `double` data type is not precise enough to represent time values with perfect accuracy. When you add `3.2986111640930176` days to `2023-07-01`, the result is indeed `2023-07-04 07:10:00`, but the underlying binary representation of double introduces slight imprecision. This imprecision affects the Ticks property of the resulting DateTime.

To avoid this issue, you should use the `decimal` data type instead of `double` when working with exact time values. The `decimal` data type offers higher precision for `decimal` calculations.

Here is how you can modify your code to use `decimal`:

```
decimal time = 3.2986111640930176m;
DateTime firstDate = new DateTime(2023, 7, 1);
DateTime newDate = firstDate.AddDays(time);
DateTime roundedDate = newDate.RoundUp(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1));

Console.WriteLine("Original Date: " + newDate);
Console.WriteLine("Rounded Date: " + roundedDate);
Console.WriteLine("Ticks: " + roundedDate.Ticks);
```

Using `decimal` will give you a more precise result and reduce the issue of imprecision with `double`. However, keep in mind that `decimal` may have slightly reduced performance compared to `double`, so it's best to use it only when you need high precision with `decimal` calculations.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but that does not work. AddDays takes a double. I tried declaring it as a decimal and casting as a double to AddDays but its still not workin.